# how to serve a video using video.js coming from diff domain?

Tags: javascript, video, video.js

I have a site coming x.com and would like to serve a video from b.com using video.js

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <video id="videoIntro" class="centerElement vjs-big-play-centered video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
                   preload="auto" poster="videoIntro.png"
                   data-setup="{}">
                <source src="b.com/StudioLite.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
            </video>
        </div>
```

but I keep getting an security box error from browser: access denied

is it possible to serve a video from diff domain using video.js ?

Thanks for reading,

Sean.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a different domain you need an absolute path including the protocol.

```
<source src="http://b.com/StudioLite.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
```